# Redirecting a button to a form in same page

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I want to use my button Reserve Button in the jumbotron to go to my form section in index.html file.
That when I click the reserve button, it will automatically take me to the form section at the bottom.

This is my button code:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-3 align-self-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block text-black">Reserve Table</button>
</div>
```

This is my form code:

```
<form >
       <--Contains form code, not posted because it wasn't needed -->   
</form>
```

Comment: And never post your full code nobody have time to read all from start to end especially giving the link of GitHub. Never ever give a link to GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that button into a link like put the button name inside the anchor tag put a name inside the href quote like the following way I did...

```
<a href="#button">button_name</a>
```

Then after giving your form an

```
id="button"
```

In this way, your auto scroll will work try it...

Comment: Thanks ,it worked. Also i appreciate your advice for making my questions look better.I will keep that in mind while asking again :)